# Invalid Qualifier error with Slope function

Tags: vba, excel

New to VBA and got this qualifier error for a code that's supposed to calculate the slope of two arrays and place it in a column with the given address.

Beats me so far, so it'd be nice to have some help! The sizes of the arrays are matching.

The compile error is given at the `.Slope` within the `TargetSheet.Cells(n, (MyRange.Columns.Count) + 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Slope(TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(n, 5), TargetSheet.Cells(n, MyRange.Columns.Count)), TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(1, 5), TargetSheet.Cells(1, MyRange.Columns.Count))).Value`

```
Dim n As Long
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet, SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetBook As Workbook

Set TargetBook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set TargetSheet = Application.ActiveSheet

For n = 3 To MyRange.Rows.Count

    TargetSheet.Cells(n, (MyRange.Columns.Count) + 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Slope(TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(n, 5), TargetSheet.Cells(n, MyRange.Columns.Count)), TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(1, 5), TargetSheet.Cells(1, MyRange.Columns.Count))).Value

Next n

End With
End Sub
```

A version before this one (can't undo till that point :/) was working up till a point where it stopped and gave the qualifier error. I used Excel's SLOPE function on the data set and compared alongside: it was giving this error at a #DIV/0 result (but the VBA didn't show that).

Comment: Remove `.Value` from the Slope function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @OldUgly! Managed to fix the error. Reason for VBA: automate for multiple data sheets in the same format with varying no. of columns and rows.

WorksheetFunction.Slope doesn't like it when there's only one data point and the rest of one array is empty.

I created another loop to count non-empty cells within the `For` loop for each row. If the no. of non-empty cells is < 2 for a particular row, the output would be "Insufficient Data".

If not, then the slope value would be calculated.

Another, less painstaking way to get around this issue is to simply use `On Error Resume Next` for this specific case.

```
Dim n As Long, o As Range, CurrentRow As Range, NonEmptyCellCountRow As Integer


For n = 3 To MyRange.Rows.Count `Within each row, counting non-empty cells

    Set CurrentRow = TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(n, 5), TargetSheet.Cells(n, MyRange.Columns.Count))

    NonEmptyCellCountRow = 0

    For Each o In CurrentRow

        If o.Value <> "" Then NonEmptyCellCountRow = NonEmptyCellCountRow + 1

    Next o

    If NonEmptyCellCountRow < 2 Then _

        TargetSheet.Cells(n, (MyRange.Columns.Count) + 1) = "Insufficient Data"

    Else

        TargetSheet.Cells(n, (MyRange.Columns.Count) + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Slope(TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(n, 5), TargetSheet.Cells(n, MyRange.Columns.Count)), TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(1, 5), TargetSheet.Cells(1, MyRange.Columns.Count)))

    End If

Next n
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated, removing .Value from the slope call allows it to pass the compiler.

Otherwise, it seems to work.

This input ...

[image]

Provided this output ...

[image]

Using this code (slightly modified to get the correct columns) ...

```
Sub main()
Dim n As Long
Dim MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet, SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetBook As Workbook

Set TargetBook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set TargetSheet = Application.ActiveSheet

For n = 2 To MyRange.Rows.Count

    TargetSheet.Cells(n, (MyRange.Columns.Count) + 1).Value = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Slope(TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(n, 1), TargetSheet.Cells(n, MyRange.Columns.Count)), _
        TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(1, 1), TargetSheet.Cells(1, MyRange.Columns.Count)))

Next n

End Sub
```

Below is revised code to capture case when only 1 Y value is present to avoid divide by zero. This assumes that row 1 in the worksheet will have nothing to the right of the headers.

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim n As Long
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim nRows As Long, nCols As Long, ColCount As Long

Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet, SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetBook As Workbook

Set TargetBook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set TargetSheet = Application.ActiveSheet

nRows = MyRange.Rows.Count
nCols = MyRange.Rows(1).End(xlToRight)

For n = 2 To nRows

    ColCount = Application.CountIf(TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(n, 1), Sheet1.Cells(n, nCols)), """<>""""""")
    If ColCount > 1 Then
        TargetSheet.Cells(n, (MyRange.Columns.Count) + 1).Value = _
            Application.Slope(TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(n, 1), TargetSheet.Cells(n, MyRange.Columns.Count)), _
            TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(1, 1), TargetSheet.Cells(1, MyRange.Columns.Count)))
    End If
Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: It worked until a "#DIV/0" error came up, as shown here:

http://i.imgur.com/oXyo1nZ.png

Comment: @StarrySky - I modified the answer to capture the case where there is only on Y value and then not calculate a slope. It relies on there being no data to the right of your dates in the first row.

Comment: remind me again why you are using VBA. This would be simple with Excel formulas: `=IF(GT(COUNTIF(C1:C7,"<>"""),1),SLOPE(C1:C7,$B$1:$B$7),"")` and then fill down.